# create a new summary variable if condition across many columns

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with an ID variable and a bunch of similarly named columns with information

```
+-------------------------------------------------
|         ID   | C1   |    C2     |   C3    | ...
+-------------------------------------------------
|          1   | 99   |  101      |   102   | ...
+-------------------------------------------------
```

I need to count the number of columns that fulfil certain condition (e.g. <100) If the number of columns was small I would do something like

```
df %>% mutate (counter= case_when(C1 <100 & C2<100 & C3<100 ~ "3",
                                  C1<100 & C2<100 ~ 2, ...)
```

But that is obviously not an option with 100+ columns. I Could also pivot, summarise and pivot back, but it also seems like not the cleanest solution. Any ideas of how to do this properly?

Answer (score 1):

We may use `rowSums` from `base R` on a logical `matrix` (`df[-1] < 100`) to get the count of elements in each row that are less than 100.

```
df$counter <- rowSums(df[-1] < 100, na.rm = TRUE)
```

`TRUE` -> 1 and `FALSE` -> 0, thus, when we take the row wise sum of logical matrix, each TRUE will be incremented as 1.

---

Or in a `dplyr` pipe

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(counter = rowSums(across(-1) < 100, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: That works beautifully. Thank you!